# Sitecore solr search by characters instead of words

Tags: solr, sitecore

I have implemented solr search with a computed field for page content. but issue s that it's searching based on words not characters like if i search "This is my post" it will return results but when searching for "his is my post" it does not match records. I assume because it stored them as word and matching so I tried both Tokenzied and UnTokenized but issue persists.
Any quick guide ?

```
       </fieldNames>
     </fieldMap>
     <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
       <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
         <field fieldName="renderings_content" returnType="text" >Sitecore.Feature.Search.Infrastructure.Fields.RenderingsContentComputedField, Sitecore.Feature.Search</field>
       </fields>
     </documentOptions>

   </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
```

My solr Query:

?q=((_fullpath:(/sitecore/content/marko*) AND (((-base_template_ids_sm:(ae3e2aaacb77453fad3eb15f9aa7a73b)  *:*) OR (base_template_ids_sm:(ae3e2aaacb77453fad3eb15f9aa7a73b) AND include_in_search_results_b:(True))) AND (base_template_ids_sm:(79b74cfd7d3a4aa4b238f754a6ca52ef) OR base_template_ids_sm:(b815c3ed17d84e78815e2b34e52fef79) OR base_template_ids_sm:(ea18699f5c764f69ba11a1336b83016e) OR base_template_ids_sm:(9f08fd0633ed467ba5e6b6a7f48c3a7a) OR base_template_ids_sm:(cea1d388d04f4b46a9bcd5c251064186)))) AND (title_t:("*lse dubai*") OR search_description_t:(*lse dubai*) OR renderings_content_t:("*lse dubai*") OR (title_t:("*lse dubai*") OR description_t:("*lse dubai*") OR renderings_content_t:("*lse dubai*")) OR (title_t:("*lse dubai*") OR search_description_t:(*lse dubai*) OR renderings_content_t:("*lse dubai*")) OR (search_description_t:(*lse dubai*) OR event_title_t:(*lse dubai*) OR renderings_content_t:("*lse dubai*")) OR (title_t:("*lse dubai*") OR search_description_t:(*lse dubai*) OR renderings_content_t:("*lse dubai*"))))&start=0&rows=2&fl=*,score&fq=(_latestversion:(True) AND _language:(en))&fq=_indexname:(marko_web_index)

Comment: This is the very core of a search engine: it looks up words, not substrings. You may of course have your go at what a word is (check NgramTokenizer), but you'll kill performance.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is search basses on suggestions. And yes, it's possible in Sitecore!

First of all, you need to configure [Suggester](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html) component on the Solr. If you will fallow the link you will see that there is a quite big number of options you can configure. Looking in [Improving the Search Experience with Solr Suggester](https://lucidworks.com/2015/03/04/solr-suggester/) might be beneficial for you.

Then you just need to use if:

```
SitecoreIndexableItem rootItem = Context.Database.GetRootItem();            
ISearchIndex index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(rootItem); //of course you can resolve index in different way or just pick one you are interested in
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    SolrSuggestQuery query = model.Term;
    SolrSuggestHandlerQueryResults result;
    SuggestHandlerQueryOptions options = new SuggestHandlerQueryOptions
    {
        Parameters = new SuggestParameters
        {
            Count = 5
        }
    };

    using (queryTimer = new Timer())
    {
        result = context.Suggest(query, options);
    }

    return result.Suggestions["NAME_OF_YOUR_SUGGESTER"].Suggestions.Select(a => new Suggestion { Term = a.Term, Payload = a.Payload});
}
```

`Suggestion` class used here `new Suggestion { Term = a.Term, Payload = a.Payload}` is custom class (not provided by Sitecore). You can use your own one.

**Important!** Suggestions search is only possible in Sitecore 9 (and up) and while using Solr.